# Error message when I try to click pics input of Facebook. Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Code:

```
def add_photos_to_post(self, pics_path):
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

picsXPATH='/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]'

photo_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, picsXPATH)))
photo_button.click()
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7B873AEF2+64226]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF7B86CC0B2+765410]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B848CC4C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B84D0BDF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B84D0D6A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B850AC17]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B84EF03F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B84C4BB1]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B8507FC1]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B84EEDD3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B84C3BEC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B84C2DD6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B84C4364]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF7B8918809+1319049]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7B853D2A8]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF7B86195E1+33553]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF7B8611A1F+1871]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF7B8917423+1313955]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF7B86D46E8+20232]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF7B86D0D04+5412]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF7B86D0DFC+5660]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF7B86C4AB1+735201]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFB66B526AD+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB673CAA68+40]
```

Comment: Seems like wait.until timed out, meaning it didn't find the element

Comment: Can you please make screenshot / provide DOM of element you're trying to find?

Comment: @Yaroslavm Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider suggesting OP to update the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.